# SQL insert random decimal between 4 and 5 + select from query in one insert query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to insert results in a table from select query + I want to generate random value, range between 4 and 5 in one insert query. This is what I have currently:

```
  INSERT INTO a(PropertyID, TestimonialID, Rating)
  SELECT b.PropertyID, b.TestimonialID 
  FROM [b]
  WHERE b.PropertyID NOT IN(SELECT a.PropertyID FROM a), -- Function for generating rating value between 4 and 5 should come here
```

How can I do this in SQL Server 2012?

### Update

I don't need the generated value to be exactly the same for all the properties.

Answer (score 4):

This is how I solved:

```
INSERT INTO a(PropertyID, TestimonialID, Rating)   SELECT b.PropertyID, b.TestimonialID, 
ROUND(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * (5-4),5) + 4 as RandomRating    FROM [b] 
WHERE b.PropertyID NOT IN(SELECT a.PropertyID FROM a)
```

Answer (score 1):

The following generates a random decimal.

```
insert into a(PropertyID, TestimonialID, Rating)
select 
    b.PropertyID, 
    b.TestimonialID, 
    (4 + RAND( (DATEPART(mm, GETDATE()) * 100000 )
    + (DATEPART(ss, GETDATE()) * 1000 )
    + DATEPART(ms, GETDATE()) )) as RandomRating
 from  
    [b]
 where  
    b.PropertyID not in (select a.PropertyID from a)
```

@EDIT: so, we need a different seed for random. If your PropertyID column is an integer then try replacing that part from the select with the following:

```
 4 + RAND(b.PropertyID) as RandomRating,
```

I have just tested this using following query and it works fine:

```
select 
    a.col, 
    -- random rating
    4 + RAND(a.col) as RandomRating
from  
(
    select 1 as col
    union select 2 as col
    union select 3 as col
    union select 4 as col
    union select 5 as col
    union select 6 as col
) a
```

Comment: it gives same rating value 4.75 for all the records, I don't need all of them to be the same

Answer (score 0):

I think a code like this will work.

```
SELECT 4.0 + CAST(RAND() AS DECIMAL(5,2))

--Result may give like this.
--4.62
```